# Trouble passing data from controller to view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using the Unsplash api to display photos in a new rails 6.0 app. I'm successfully able to access photos using the API directly in the view:

```
<%= image_tag Unsplash::Photo.find('_wcgFg4GC5A')[:urls][:small] %>
```

I would like to move that out of the view, however. So, I now have this in my controller:

```
@photo = Unsplash::Photo.find('_wcgFg4GC5A')[:urls][:small]
```

and I've updated the view:

```
<%= image_tag @photo %>
```

Refreshing the site after these changes returns this error: "Nil location provided. Can't build URI."

It's been a few years since I've touched Ruby/Rails, so I'm sure it's something silly. Any suggestions?

Comment: if you log that out in the controller what is returned from @photo? (maybe add it as an edit to the question itself instead of a comment)   Also, are you sure you put this in the correct controller method?

Comment: Yep, it's in the right method (the one and only method). Adding @photo? to the method seems to have no effect.

Comment: Well, I just restarted my server and now I'm getting "uninitialized constant WelcomeController" so something is clearly up with my controller

Comment: ...and restarted once more and now it all seems to be working again. Can't explain this one!

Comment: Is it spring running? Are you somehow preloading your code?